# Python Selenium print inspect element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Struggling to print inspect element code, I'm trying to print anything within

```
<div class="sub-footer tiny-footer gradient">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "inner HTML", use `get_attribute()` method to get it:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.sub-footer")
print(elm.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```